# How can people assume this angle is exactly half of the other angle?

Tags: geometry

Long story short what I don't understand is underlined here in red:
[image]

So, they somehow seem to assume the angle on the triangle on the right has an angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$.

How do they know that? How can they assume it is exactly half of the angle of theta?

Thanks

EDIT: to give a bit more of a context, it has to do with the mapping of a rocket's position in the ground-fixed coordinates to the spherical earth's coordinates. When going from one coordinate  to the other the altitude varies.

Comment: How was the triangle on the left constructed?

Comment: Is this something related to physics?

Comment: @ThomasShelby yes this is related to physics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an isoscales triangle between the circle center $C$ and the 2 points $A$ and $B$ where the lines through the center meet the circle. The angle at $C$ is $\theta$, so each base angle is $90^\circ-\frac\theta2 = \angle CAB$. Since the tangent has a right angle with the radius ($\angle CAD=90^\circ$), the angle under consideration ($\angle BAD)$ is $\frac\theta2$.

[image]

Comment: If you could provide a small ugly drawing to clarify what you mean, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @traducerad Added the picture

Comment: @ThomasShelby You think the assumption that (in my notation) $CA$ is a radius and $AD$ a tangent is strange?

Comment: Great answer @Ingix

Comment: I was confused by the drawing too. @traducerad I thought the circle sketch at the lower left represented a different circle, one that passed through the center of the shaded circle

Comment: Great question @traducerad btw!

Comment: @Ingix Oh,my bad. You're 100% right.(+1)